# Entity Configuration issue The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 tables. `Tutor` and `User`. **One user will have One Tutor** (One-to-One relationship) and that is the relationship.

I get this exception:

> An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'App.inf.dt.DatabaseContext'.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Tutors_Users_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "PIMP22", table "dbo.Users", column 'Id'.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

My entity configuration is shown here:

```
builder.HasOne(c => c.Tutor)
            .WithOne(c => c.User)
            .HasForeignKey<Tutor>(cc => cc.UserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

I wonder if there's any issue with my entity configuration? Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Note: I have a `User` record already saved in the DB. The `ID` is 1.

UPDATE

```
List<User> u = new List<User>
{
       Name= "User 1",
};

                
databaseContext.Users.AddRange(u);

List<Tutor> t = new List<Tutor>
{
       DisplayName = "tut1",
       UserId = 1
};

                
databaseContext.Tutors.AddRange(t);

await databaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Show us the code that causes this exception !

Comment: I have added the relevent code block. Do let me know if you require any other information. Thanks.

Comment: can u show us ```User``` and ```Tutor``` classes with navigation properties ?

Comment: Well, you don't have a user with UserId = 1 in the database. What's the use of this `List<User> u`? Also, you better show the classes too. And give the EF core version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can u define your relationship like that and try to update again ?

`User` class is gonna be :

```
//No relationship properties
builder.HasOne<Tutor>(x => x.Tutor)
    .WithOne(x => x.User)
    .HasForeignKey<Tutor>(x => x.UserID);
```

`Tutor` class is gonna be :

```
public int UserID { get; set; }
public virtual User User{ get; set; }

builder.HasOne<User>(x=> x.User)
    .WithOne(x=> x.Tutor)
    .HasForeignKey<Tutor>(x=> x.UserID)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Comment: That's basically the same mapping as OP already had. Only the `OnDelete` call is added. For the rest both mappings do the same thing and one mapping would suffice. I don't see how this solves the issue.

Comment: @GertArnold one-to-one is a tricky relationship. in my way, u are just keeping one foreign key which is enough the call,crud the related data. that's why we need to define the other side which has no foreignKey. if u wont define the other side, u wont able to reach that related data.

Answer (score 1):

You said there is a user with id 1 in database.

You're creating a new one and adding to the context without Tutor

```
List<User> u = new List<User>
{
   Name= "User 1",
};
databaseContext.Users.AddRange(u);
```

if the context requires a tutor for the new user created it will throw exception (you can catch it using validationerrors)

What if create a virtual prop and add the tutor referencing the object? Forget about the id, it will be auto-assigned by EF using scope_identity()

```
User.Tutor = new Tutor { DisplayName = "tut1"}
```